# Some Google Apps Accounts Stuck On "Waiting for Sync"

Tags: sync, email, gmail

I have several Google Apps (Free Edition) and one traditional Gmail acct set into my Nexus 4 (stock 4.2.2). All accts use 2FA ([2 factor authentication](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=180744)).

Using the gmail app, all (GApps & Gmail) but two (both GApps) of those accounts are able to retrieve/sync emails successfully. The settings on the *[Forwarding and POP/IMAP](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/fwdandpop)* are identical for all accounts.

I've tried removing the accts, force stop & clear data on gmail app, then recreating both accounts. I've tried leaving (for long periods of time) the auto-sync checkbox ON for those accts. I tried the [fix outlined in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GT5uHXLO298) (Auto-Sync data was already enabled, but I disabled, exited, then re-enabled).

**What else can I try to get those two accounts working!?**

Comment: Is this a problem you've had from the beginning, or did it suddenly start? For how long does the problem already exist? Can you sync manually? I had something comparable about two weeks ago and almost went nuts not finding the cause. After 2 days the problem suddenly disappeared. So it might as well be "temporary hick-ups" of the server.

Comment: It also happened on the old Samsung Galaxy One. I just got a Nexus 4 and the problem persists. On the SGS the problem was more prevalent. Regardless, it has been going on the Nexus 4 for a couple days now.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using your main Gmail password, or a 1-time use password.

Check out this link 
http://support.google.com/mail/answer/1173270?hl=en

Comment: To add a Google account, at least on 4.2.x, you have to enter the main password.